# How to bind datepicker to viewModel?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

How to get value from DatePicker and set it in variable in ViewModel?
In my xaml file I have date picker like:

```xml
<DatePicker x:Name="dateTo"
    TextColor="White"
    FontSize="Small"
    Date="{Binding DateTo}"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    IsVisible="{Binding DateToPickerVisibility}"
    Margin="5,0,0,0"
    IsEnabled="False"/>
```

In my ViewModel I have property

```cs
public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
```

and set it's value in InidData method:

```cs
DateTo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
```

But how to change that value when date is changed and "OK" button on picker is clicked?

Comment: You appear to be doing it correctly.  Is it not working?

Comment: Date is correct set on appearing, so it's just like placeholder, but how to get it's value when another date is selected and OK button is clicked?
How to Bind some command to datepicker?

Comment: You might want to review how MVVM works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm your view model needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or else the UI doesn't know when something happens.

Comment: When the user updates the DatePicker the binding mechanism should automatically update `DateTo`.  That's the whole point of using DataBinding, to free the developer from having to do it manually.

Comment: @AndresCastro I saw that, but my ViewModel already inherits another model, and that another model alreadz inherits another model... :D
I think itćs gonna be to dificult to implement on that way.

Comment: @NitrusBrio INotifyPropertyChanged is an interface. You can inherit your model and many different interfaces. There should be no conflict.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is about updating the UI when the model changes, but you are asking about the opposite, updating the model when the UI changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your ViewModel need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`,so that the DatePicker could update the value automatically.

There is a full demo which works properly. The main code is :

```
 public class DateViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _dateToPickerVisibility;

    public bool DateToPickerVisibility
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _dateToPickerVisibility, value); }
        get { return _dateToPickerVisibility; }
    }

    DateTime _dateTo;
    public DateTime DateTo
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _dateTo, value); }
        get { return _dateTo; }
    }

    public DateViewModel()
    {
        DateTo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
        DateToPickerVisibility = true;
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <DatePicker x:Name="dateTo"
                FontSize="Small"
                Date="{Binding DateTo}"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                IsVisible="{Binding DateToPickerVisibility}"
                Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

    <Button x:Name="mButton" 
            Text="Hide DatePicker"
            Clicked="MButton_Clicked"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            />
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
    DateViewModel dateViewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dateViewModel = new DateViewModel();
        BindingContext = dateViewModel;

    }

    private void MButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dateViewModel.DateToPickerVisibility) {
            dateViewModel.DateToPickerVisibility = false;
            mButton.Text = "Make DatePicker visible";
        }
        else {
            dateViewModel.DateToPickerVisibility = true;
            mButton.Text = "Hide DatePicker";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1.You can init the value in the constructor of your ViewModel.e.g.

```
 public DateViewModel()
    {
        DateTo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
        DateToPickerVisibility = true;
    }
```

2.To make the datePicker visible or hidden,  I added a Button to change the value of `DateToPickerVisibility`.

```
  private void MButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dateViewModel.DateToPickerVisibility) {
            dateViewModel.DateToPickerVisibility = false;
            mButton.Text = "Make DatePicker visible";
        }
        else {
            dateViewModel.DateToPickerVisibility = true;
            mButton.Text = "Hide DatePicker";
        }
    }
```

The result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML looks fine.

Your property in the ViewModel, however, isn't invoking `PropertyChanged`. When the value of a Property in the ViewModel changes, it needs to call `PropertyChanged?.Invoke` to alert/update the View.

Here's an example of the XAML, its Code-Behind and its ViewModel:

### XAML

```xml
<DatePicker x:Name="dateTo"
    TextColor="White"
    FontSize="Small"
    Date="{Binding DateTo}"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    IsVisible="{Binding DateToPickerVisibility}"
    Margin="5,0,0,0"
    IsEnabled="False"/>
```

### Code Behind

```cs
public partial class MyView
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

### ViewModel

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _dateToPickerVisibility
    DateTime _dateTo

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DateTime DateTo
    {
        get => _dateTo;
        set
        {
            _dateTo = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DateTo)));
        }
    }

    public bool DateToPickerVisibility
    {
        get => _dateToPickerVisibility;
        set 
        {
            _dateToPickerVisibility = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DateToPickerVisibility)));
        }
    }
}
```